# Conditional distribution of random variable X given itself

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm stuck with something that might seem trivial but gives me headache.
What is the distribution of $X|X$, i.e. the conditional distribution of $X$ given $X$?

I'm pretty confident that:

$$\mathbb P(X\le t|X\le s)=\frac{\mathbb P(X\le t  \cap X\le s)}{\mathbb P(X\le s)}=\frac{\mathbb P(X\le t)}{\mathbb P(X\le s)}$$
if $t\le s$ and
$$\mathbb P(X\le t|X\le s)=1$$ otherwise, $t>s$.
However from this point onwards, I am confused.
My intuitive answer would be that the conditional distribution $X|X$ is either the distribution of $X$ or $1$ (but a distribution equal to $1$ doesn't make any sense).

P.S. I believe this is related to the question what is the joint distribution of X with itself, $f_{XX}(x,x)$, by
$$f_{XX}(x,x)=f_{X|X}(x|x)\cdot f_{X}(x)$$
but I can't find $f_{XX}(x,x)$ either.

Comment: $X|X\sim \delta_X$. The first equation should read $=\frac {P(X\le t)}{P(X\le s)}$ and the second one $=1$.

Comment: I'm sorry you're right, I'll edit.

Comment: Note that the pdf $f_{X\mid X}$ is not defined because $f_{X, X}$ is not defined. Suppose $X$ is a real-valued continuous random variable. Then, the random vector $Z=(X, X)$ takes values only on the "diagonal" $E = \{(x, y)\in{\rm I\!R}^2: x= y\}$, which has Lebesgue measure zero, but ${\rm P}[Z\in E] = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution of $X$ conditional on itself, $X\mid\sigma(X)$ is indeed just $X$. But that's not what you're doing here. Instead you're conditioning on $\sigma(A)$ for some $A\in\sigma(X)$. Your computation of $F_{X\mid X\leqslant s}(t)$ is correct, as if $t\geqslant s$ then $$\mathbb P(X\leqslant t\mid X\leqslant s)\geqslant\mathbb P(X\leqslant s\mid X\leqslant s)=1.$$ By the way, it is not a distribution here that is equal to $1$, but rather the probability of an event (conditioned on a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\sigma(X)$). As for the joint distribution of $X$ with itself, we have for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$
$$F_{X,X}(x,y) = \mathbb P(X\leqslant x,X\leqslant y)=\mathbb P(X\leqslant x\wedge y)=F_X(x\wedge y). $$

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my approach was not the right one then. Nevertheless, how do I rigorously prove that $X|X$ distributes as $X$ itself? Can I write: $f_X (x)=f_{X|X} (x,y)$ ?

Comment: One rigorously writes that $X\mid X$ distributes as $X$ itself because $\mathbb E[X\mid X]$ is by definition $X$. Look up the (measure-theoretic) definition of conditional expectation.